# Salesforce SOAP / Metadata API login - Python

Tags: python, soap, salesforce, zeep

I'm using Python [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) to use SOAP to interact with Salesforce's Metadata API.

I'm attempting to start with the simplest thing possible, just log in and read a metadata object.

```
from zeep import Client as zClient

client = zClient('sf_config/sf_metadata_40.xml',
                 wsse=UsernameToken('bub@bob.com', 'scary_secretPassW*rd')

// readMetadata method exists, prints <zeep.client.OperationProxy object at ...>
print client.service.readMetadata

// errors because login method does not exist
print client.service.login
```

The thing is, Salesforce requires you to change the endpoint you're pointing at to be a URL you get in the response of your login request ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_calls_intro.htm)). But I don't know how to make such a login call. My above code seems to hide that login call by using username and password in the construction of the `client` object.

Thus, executing the `readMetadata` method like this `client.service.readMetadata()` caused this error:
`Fault: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService`

So my question is how can I make that login call for a SOAP API in Python?

(The Java examples in Salesforce [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm) use a `connection` object that I'm not really sure what the Python zeep equivalent would be, so I don't have an example to go off of.)

EDIT:
By the way, I have asked on the Salesforce stack exchange, but figured this may be possible to answer by someone who knows `zeep` even if they don't know Salesforce, so worth posting here as well.

UPDATE:
For authentication, I've already used OAuth flow to get access token, for use with REST API, so I'll reuse that auth method / access token. That changes my question to:

1) How do I use the access token (which I believe replaces sessionID) to then make requests to Metadata API?
2) If I use OAuth flow to get access token, I'm still missing Metadata API server url, so how can I get that (or construct it, like `https://server-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/40.0/orgId` or something)?

Comment: You'll need to also import the partner WSDL so you can call login [that wsse UsernameToken thing is doing nothing that'll work]. Or you can use the OAuth flows to get a sessionId / serverURL. But if you're set on SOAP, grab the partner WSDL to be able to call login.

Comment: Oh, there's an OAuth (non-SOAP) way to get that? I'm definitely not set on SOAP. Just wasn't aware of alternatives. I'll search for that now, but just in case, do you have link for OAuth stuff that works for then calling Metadata API?

Comment: EDIT: I actually already know how to use OAuth since I use it to then interact with the REST API, so I don't need docs/help with that. How does it come into play with the Metadata API though? That's really what I'm unsure of.

Comment: Sorry for many comments, I'm honing in my question over time. What I'm really wondering is how to get the Metadata API server url if OAuth replaces the login request that normally returns that? (That request also returns sessionID but I know that the OAuth access token replaces that.)

Comment: the oauth response include the instanceUrl which you can use to build the url to the metadata API.